# Newman command not found

Tags: api, testing, postman, newman

I am trying to run m collection through jenkins but it shows below error:

> ** Started by user trideep mukherjee Running as SYSTEM Building in workspace
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Newman [Newman] $
> cmd /c call C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\jenkins8980552465408575800.bat C:\Program
> Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Newman>cd
> C:\Users\tride\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\newman
> C:\Users\tride\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\newman>newman
> --version *‘newman’ is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.*
> C:\Users\tride\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\newman>exit 9009 Build
> step 'Ex**

I have tried the all possible ways mention in the blog to add the local path of the newman but didn’t worked.
Please see the environment variable I have added

Answer (score 0):

Set newman installation path to path in windows or in linux as environment variable.
Then it will work